# Is there any way to refresh GTM container manually?

Tags: google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

After I published the container in the console of Google Tag Manager, I found that the container in my App was still using the default(old) container. Is there any way that I can refresh users' container forcibly?

I am building an Android App to study features of the newest version of Google Tag Manager with Firebase.

I know there was Container.refresh() in GTM v3 but it seems not appearing in the latest version(v5?).

Answer (score 0):

prablely nope, GTM delployed in your app will only update to the latest version once it contect to Internet. Guess that you can only rebuild your APP with a newer version of GTM json file .